# WordPress How to capture data from forms submitted by users

Tags: wordpress

I want to collect data when the user fills out the form and submits the form.

Once the data is collected, I want display the submitted data on an another page in a table form.

I'm not sure how to achieve this WordPress, please guide me how this can be achieved.

Most of the data will be numeric and displayed results will be calculated.

thanks
Neil

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you use POST method in your form, and that when the user click on submit button it will go to mypage.php (or the page in action attribute of the form. Then, in that mypage.php you get the values of the form using $_POST variable.

For example if the form is

```
<form action="mypage.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" id="mytext" name="mytext" value="write a text">
</form>
```

then *$_POST['mytext']*
will let you know the user entry.

If you used GET method instead, it's the same, but with *$_GET['mytext']*

Comment: I'm new to PHP and SQL, I can work around my in WordPress. I want to accomplish this in WordPress with plugins.